# Fix aspnetboilerplate startup template, tenant or edit with errors

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying AspBoilerPlate as a framework because it looks really good and I've been having a hard time trying to get multitenancy on Owin Identity (I posted a question some days ago: [Asp.Net Identity Multitenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046934/asp-net-identity-multitenant)

I downloaded the Asp.Net MVC so I can port the code I already have, the right from scratch the loads I can login create users, tenants but, **on any view if I click Edit It says Error ocurred, at login view if I click change Tenant an error ocurred.**

This are the steps I took (Tried both ASP.Net MVC and Core versions):

1. Download / Unpack / Open and load on VS 2019
2. Change connection string on web.config
3. Run the Update-Database from console on EntityFramework project
4. Start the App

It works but with the erros I described above.

I used step into function on VS to try to get the real error, but it might be catching it on an external dll or something, Here is the clean log.txt only doing Load-Login-Change tenant(error) - Login - Edit tenant (error)

```
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:12:59,986 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Found 17 ABP modules in total.
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:12:59,995 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: myapplication.Web.myapplicationWebModule, myapplication.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:12:59,997 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: myapplication.myapplicationDataModule, myapplication.EntityFramework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:12:59,997 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: Abp.Zero.EntityFramework.AbpZeroEntityFrameworkModule, Abp.Zero.EntityFramework, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:12:59,998 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: Abp.Zero.AbpZeroCoreModule, Abp.Zero, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:12:59,999 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: Abp.Zero.AbpZeroCommonModule, Abp.Zero.Common, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:12:59,999 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: Abp.AbpKernelModule, Abp, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:00,006 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: Abp.EntityFramework.AbpEntityFrameworkModule, Abp.EntityFramework, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:00,006 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: Abp.EntityFramework.AbpEntityFrameworkCommonModule, Abp.EntityFramework.Common, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:00,007 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: myapplication.myapplicationCoreModule, myapplication.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:00,007 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: myapplication.myapplicationApplicationModule, myapplication.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:00,012 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: Abp.AutoMapper.AbpAutoMapperModule, Abp.AutoMapper, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:00,012 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: myapplication.Api.myapplicationWebApiModule, myapplication.WebApi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:00,013 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: Abp.WebApi.AbpWebApiModule, Abp.Web.Api, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:00,013 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: Abp.Web.AbpWebModule, Abp.Web, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:00,013 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: Abp.Web.AbpWebCommonModule, Abp.Web.Common, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:00,014 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: Abp.Web.SignalR.AbpWebSignalRModule, Abp.Web.SignalR, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:00,014 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - Loaded module: Abp.Web.Mvc.AbpWebMvcModule, Abp.Web.Mvc, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:00,018 [1    ] Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager             - 17 modules loaded.
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:03,252 [1    ] o.Configuration.LanguageManagementConfig - Converted Abp (Abp.Localization.Dictionaries.DictionaryBasedLocalizationSource) to MultiTenantLocalizationSource
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:03,252 [1    ] o.Configuration.LanguageManagementConfig - Converted AbpZero (Abp.Localization.Dictionaries.DictionaryBasedLocalizationSource) to MultiTenantLocalizationSource
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:03,252 [1    ] o.Configuration.LanguageManagementConfig - Converted myapplication (Abp.Localization.Dictionaries.DictionaryBasedLocalizationSource) to MultiTenantLocalizationSource
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:03,252 [1    ] o.Configuration.LanguageManagementConfig - Converted AbpWeb (Abp.Localization.Dictionaries.DictionaryBasedLocalizationSource) to MultiTenantLocalizationSource
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:03,865 [1    ] EntityFramework.AbpEntityFrameworkModule - Registering DbContext: myapplication.EntityFramework.myapplicationDbContext, myapplication.EntityFramework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,085 [1    ] Abp.Localization.LocalizationManager     - Initializing 4 localization sources.
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,161 [1    ] Abp.Localization.LocalizationManager     - Initialized localization source: Abp
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,219 [1    ] Abp.Localization.LocalizationManager     - Initialized localization source: AbpZero
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,247 [1    ] Abp.Localization.LocalizationManager     - Initialized localization source: myapplication
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,280 [1    ] Abp.Localization.LocalizationManager     - Initialized localization source: AbpWeb
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,391 [1    ] Abp.BackgroundJobs.BackgroundJobManager  - Start background worker: Castle.Proxies.BackgroundJobManagerProxy
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,468 [1    ] Abp.AutoMapper.AbpAutoMapperModule       - Found 11 classes define auto mapping attributes
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,469 [1    ] Abp.AutoMapper.AbpAutoMapperModule       - myapplication.Sessions.Dto.TenantLoginInfoDto
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,477 [1    ] Abp.AutoMapper.AbpAutoMapperModule       - myapplication.Sessions.Dto.UserLoginInfoDto
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,478 [1    ] Abp.AutoMapper.AbpAutoMapperModule       - myapplication.Users.Dto.CreateUserDto
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,479 [1    ] Abp.AutoMapper.AbpAutoMapperModule       - myapplication.Users.Dto.UpdateUserDto
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,479 [1    ] Abp.AutoMapper.AbpAutoMapperModule       - myapplication.Users.Dto.UserDto
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,479 [1    ] Abp.AutoMapper.AbpAutoMapperModule       - myapplication.Roles.Dto.PermissionDto
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,479 [1    ] Abp.AutoMapper.AbpAutoMapperModule       - myapplication.MultiTenancy.Dto.CreateTenantDto
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,480 [1    ] Abp.AutoMapper.AbpAutoMapperModule       - myapplication.MultiTenancy.Dto.EditTenantDto
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,480 [1    ] Abp.AutoMapper.AbpAutoMapperModule       - myapplication.MultiTenancy.Dto.TenantDto
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,480 [1    ] Abp.AutoMapper.AbpAutoMapperModule       - myapplication.Web.Models.Account.TenantChangeViewModel
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:06,480 [1    ] Abp.AutoMapper.AbpAutoMapperModule       - myapplication.Web.Models.Account.TenantSelectionViewModel+TenantInfo
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:08,736 [1    ] Abp.Logging.LogHelper                    - Dynamic web api controller is created for type 'myapplication.Sessions.ISessionAppService' with service name 'app/session'.
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:08,737 [1    ] Abp.Logging.LogHelper                    - Dynamic web api controller is created for type 'myapplication.Users.IUserAppService' with service name 'app/user'.
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:08,738 [1    ] Abp.Logging.LogHelper                    - Dynamic web api controller is created for type 'myapplication.Roles.IRoleAppService' with service name 'app/role'.
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:08,739 [1    ] Abp.Logging.LogHelper                    - Dynamic web api controller is created for type 'myapplication.MultiTenancy.ITenantAppService' with service name 'app/tenant'.
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:08,740 [1    ] Abp.Logging.LogHelper                    - Dynamic web api controller is created for type 'myapplication.Configuration.IConfigurationAppService' with service name 'app/configuration'.
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:13:08,741 [1    ] Abp.Logging.LogHelper                    - Dynamic web api controller is created for type 'myapplication.Authorization.Accounts.IAccountAppService' with service name 'app/account'.
WARN  2019-09-24 13:13:26,032 [6    ] Abp.Logging.LogHelper                    - Abp.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationException: Current user did not login to the application!
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelper.<AuthorizeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelper.<CheckPermissions>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelper.<AuthorizeAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnwrapException(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<Run>b__0(Task t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnwrapException(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.Run(Func`1 action)
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelperExtensions.Authorize(IAuthorizationHelper authorizationHelper, MethodInfo methodInfo, Type type)
   at Abp.Web.Mvc.Authorization.AbpMvcAuthorizeFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
Abp.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationException: Current user did not login to the application!
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelper.<AuthorizeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelper.<CheckPermissions>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelper.<AuthorizeAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnwrapException(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<Run>b__0(Task t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnwrapException(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.Run(Func`1 action)
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelperExtensions.Authorize(IAuthorizationHelper authorizationHelper, MethodInfo methodInfo, Type type)
   at Abp.Web.Mvc.Authorization.AbpMvcAuthorizeFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:15:15,987 [12   ] Abp.Web.SignalR.Hubs.AbpCommonHub        - A client is connected: {"ConnectionId":"93594c5a-5aa2-40be-af8e-c3487535bd12","IpAddress":"192.168.42.1","TenantId":null,"UserId":1,"ConnectTime":"2019-09-24T13:15:15.9774976-06:00","Properties":{}}
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:15:16,020 [6    ] Abp.Web.SignalR.Hubs.AbpCommonHub        - A client is registered: 93594c5a-5aa2-40be-af8e-c3487535bd12
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:15:28,150 [10   ] Abp.Web.SignalR.Hubs.AbpCommonHub        - A client is disconnected: 93594c5a-5aa2-40be-af8e-c3487535bd12
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:15:30,882 [12   ] Abp.Web.SignalR.Hubs.AbpCommonHub        - A client is connected: {"ConnectionId":"e9afe71e-bc64-4c18-a66c-a7381fae6701","IpAddress":"192.168.42.1","TenantId":null,"UserId":1,"ConnectTime":"2019-09-24T13:15:30.8823332-06:00","Properties":{}}
DEBUG 2019-09-24 13:15:30,889 [6    ] Abp.Web.SignalR.Hubs.AbpCommonHub        - A client is registered: e9afe71e-bc64-4c18-a66c-a7381fae6701
WARN  2019-09-24 13:15:35,697 [9    ] naries.DictionaryBasedLocalizationSource - Can not find 'EditTenant' in localization source 'myapplication'!
```

I was wondering if the free version didn't work from scratch, I've been looking for errors like this but everybody seems to get it working, and have the problems after they start changing code.

The reason I wasn’t getting the error on the debug is because is happening at javascript-ajax call, jquery.js on fuction:

```
jQuery.parseJSON = function( data ) {
    return JSON.parse( data + "" );
};
```

The data parameter is receiving:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">
        <span>Change tenant</span>
    </h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <form name="TenantChangeForm" role="form" novalidate class="form-validation">
        <div class="form-group form-float">
            <div class="form-line">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="TenancyName" maxlength="64">
                <label class="form-label">Tenancy name</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="help-block">Leave empty to switch to the host</span>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default close-button waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save-button waves-effect">Save</button>
</div>

<script src="/Views/Account/_TenantChangeModal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Witch give the error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.**

And returns to abp.jquery.js :

```
 }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
              if (jqXHR.responseJSON && jqXHR.responseJSON.__abp) {
                abp.ajax.handleResponse(jqXHR.responseJSON, userOptions, $dfd, jqXHR);
              } else {
                abp.ajax.handleNonAbpErrorResponse(jqXHR, userOptions, $dfd);
              }
```

Ive been looking and all modals won't show and all view contain a JS to show like this:

```
(function () {
    $('.tenant-change-component a')
        .click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            abp.ajax({
                url: abp.appPath + 'Account/TenantChangeModal',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/html',
                success: function (content) {
                    $('#TenantChangeModal div.modal-content').html(content);
                },
                error: function (e) { }
            });
        });
})();
```

The problem is related to modal, but only on change tenant and edits tenant, if I try create tenant or user it works.

After going to the JSON.Parse and receiving the entire view as parameter it gets a parser error and this: jqXHR.status get status 200.

Added a Watch to the data variable and with the modals that work never gets the entire view as parameter keeps null. Tried modify the function to always return null but screen only gets dark.

Also tried to update jquery.js to 2.2.4(below 3), because the template uses 2.2.0. and still the same problem.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Thank you for your response, when I click on Change Tenant or Edit on any view it throws An Error has Ocurred, error detail not sent by server. Tried to trace it but it goes all the way and then just shows the error.  The Log.txt that the software provides is the one that I included. Is there any other way to get more information?.  I tried the core and asp.net mvc and both the same problem, I just tried the version with Angular and works fine, but don't know anything about Angular and I have no time to learn right now.  Thank you.

Comment: The logs that you posted do not show any error. Is there any error in the browser console? What's the status coffee in the browser Network tab?

Comment: I checked on Chrome Network information and no error even I see a preview of what it should look like the tenant change. The log I posted at the end have some exceptions thrown.  I uploaded the code to Github https://github.com/menendeze/AbpTrouble

Comment: Can you share screenshots?

Comment: This is the screenshot of localhost: https://imgur.com/a/Ft2w9cS . Thats a new download of template, nothing changed just connection string and Update-Database command. I Uploaded to a temp url: http://menendeze-001-site3.gtempurl.com/ user and password default admin 123qwe   I checked the network information of the online site and cant find the famfamfam-flags.png, checked on the online folder and is there, on local host wont show that.

Comment: Did you check if tenant has an Id? I can see TenantId is null in your error stack. Perhaps, you're not logged in any tenant. Ps: we use aspnet boilerplate in production where I work. It's pretty easy to bootstrap it and use it. Probably it's something very small to make it run.

Comment: Doesn't have a tenant Id because it fails right after you click on change tenant, It has to be with Modals, thats why I'm not able to use any edit view, like edit users or edit tenant: I can create them, but everytime it is a modal it throws error. In production you can check this: menendeze-001-site3.gtempurl.com This is fresh nothing changed no even packages updated (I tried updating packages too).

Comment: @menendeze Post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the question on GitHub:
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/4889

And it's solved by doing some changes on the Index.js (or Default.js) of the views that fire a modal:

```
Replace: $.ajax({

With: abp.ajax({
```

and

```
Replace: contentType: 'application/html',

With: dataType: 'html',
```

The commit:
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/pull/169/commits/9105e33b327b6885a0e1aafbd20d7ff092860646

<sub>*Added on behalf of question asker.*</sub>